# HTML: Громоздкая разметка или новые теги?

Tags: html, css

Известно, что в современности можно вводить свои теги с стилизовать их через css. Это полезно столько на этапе вёрстки сайта, сколько на этапе его эксплуатации при добавлении новых записей.

Допустим, Вы через панель своей CMS вводите новую статью и хотите что-то выделить жирным и ещё красным. Это наверняка будет вставлено в код в виде

```
<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold"> текст </span>
```

Но если таких красных жирных слов будет много, тогда разметка будет очень нагромождённой (да, её пользователи смотреть не будут, но всё равно код станет абсолютно нечитабельным для разработчиков).

Если же заменить этот span на свой стилизованный в другом файле тег, код станет куда более читабельным:

```
<kinovar> slovo </kinovar>
```

Вопрос: какие проблемы могут возникнуть при ислользовании своих тэгов?
Ну со старыми браузерами всё понятно, а в новых какие?

Comment: проблемы только с валидатором , а всё остальное будет тип топ , вот это же работает у вас ? http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/mEgdYx

Comment: Да, работает. Я уже вставлял свои теги и тоже всё работало, просто я задаюсь вопросом: раз новые теги действительно дают много новых возможностей, то почему их не используют? Вроде как времени, сил и денег на вёрстку специально для пользователей старых браузеров выделяют всё меньше.

Comment: может и используют но просто сайтов таких не видно да и ввели это совсем не давно , а новшества как понимаете не каждый воспринимает адекватно

Answer (score 1):

Для этого должна быть весомая причина. С тем, что вы описали - справится обычный class. Добавление новых тегов может ещё больше запутать разработчика.

Я думаю, добавление нового тега имеет смысл при создании нового элемента (например, календаря), который будет обрабатываться javascript'ом.

К тому же следует помнить, что поисковые системы учитывают семантику при анализе страницы. По этому лучше использовать новые теги только для элементов интерфейса.

Comment: я согласен насчёт "справится обычный class", но всё равно <kinovar> короче чем <span class="kinovar">.  Я тут подумал: если требуется элегантность кода, который видят только пользователи и администраторы, то может при вводе новых публикаций через CMS программно организовать замену <kinovar> на <span class="kinovar">?

Comment: Если это действительно имеет смысл и на это есть время, то почему бы и нет!